# jquery function works on select but not multiselect

Tags: jquery

```
$('select').change(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    if($('#' + id + ' option[value="Other"]:selected').length > 0){
        $('#' + id + '-other').prop('disabled', false);
        $('#' + id + '-other').prop('hidden', false);
    }
});
```

The above function works perfectly on a normal select tag, but not on one with the multiple property.  I feel like I am missing something about the difference between them.

Basically, I have a hidden && disabled field that needs to become enabled and visible whenever the user selects "Other" options in any select tag, including ones with the multiple tag.

EDIT: There is a hidden && disabled field per select

EDIT 2: I apologize: the hidden field is another type of input, it is not another option.

EDIT 3: Here is [my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t81dhnh7/4/) that I just made. Does not work on jQuery 3.2.1 but any older ones including 3.1.1 work fine.  From this, I have concluded there must be something ELSE wrong in my original code causing problems.  I cannot imagine what.

EDIT 4: The real problem was the following:

```
$('option').mousedown(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).prop('selected', $(this).prop('selected') ? false : true);
    return false;
});
```

This prevented a select with multiple to not behave correctly.  How would I modify this in order to preserve the desired behavior and have my hidden fields on both type of selects?  Fiddle link has been updated as well.

Comment: Your jsfiddle-script is basically OK (there are a few redundant bits ...) but the problem seems to be the jquery library 3.2.1: it works, when you choose "jquery edge" instead (version: 3.2.2-pre c1c549793a8772107e128d21f8a8f0c3fdf0f027)

Comment: @cars10 my original problem isn't about the jquery version.  The fact that it doesn't work with 3.2.1 was something i stumbled upon while trying to solve the posted problem.

Comment: OK ... but it works now - doesn't it ?!? So where *is* the problem?

Comment: no, if you read my edit three I clearly said that "I have concluded there must be something ELSE wrong in my original code causing problem" because even though in my fiddle it is working, it is not working in my source code

Comment: Well, it is up to you to provide an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ... ;-) - the examples visible to everybody here at Stackoverflow *have* been solved.

Comment: updated example

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
$('select.first').click(function(){
 var $trg=$('#'+$(this).attr('id')+'-other');
 var state=!$('option[value="Other"]:selected',this).length;
 $trg.prop('hidden',state).prop('disabled',state);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id='one' class="first" multiple="true">
<option value="a">A</option>
<option value="b">B</option>
<option value="c">C</option>
<option value="d">D</option>
<option value="e">E</option>
<option value="Other">Other options</option>
</select>
<input id="one-other" type="text" hidden="true" disabled="true"><br>
<select id='two' class="first" multiple="true">
<option value="f">F</option>
<option value="g">G</option>
<option value="h">H</option>
<option value="i">I</option>
<option value="j">J</option>
<option value="Other">Other options</option>
</select>
<input id="two-other" type="text" hidden="true" disabled="true">
```

I based the whole action on the `click` event, since this triggers immediately and leaves the user the option of clicking the previously invisible options. I also simplified the selector for changing the visibility and clickability since it does not harm for the already visible options to be made visible again.

**2. Edit**
OP now made clear that the "other option" is in fact a different input element. I adjusted my answer accordingly and hope this fits ...

Comment: See my second edit.  Also, I didn't know you could embed snippets like that

Comment: I have a working example of the issue now on the fiddle.  See fourth and hopefully final edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following markup to achieve this.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#selectMenu").change(function(){
   var val = $(this).val();
   if(val=="Other"){
    $("#textField1, #textField2").attr('disabled',false);
    $("#textField1, #textField2").removeClass('hidden');

   }else{
    $("#textField1, #textField2").attr('disabled',true);
    $("#textField1, #textField2").addClass('hidden');
   }
  });
});
```

```css
 
.hidden{display: none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id='selectMenu' multiple="true">
<option value="a">A</option>
<option value="b">B</option>
<option value="c">C</option>
<option value="d">D</option>
<option value="e">E</option>
<option value="Other">Other options</option>

</select>



<div class="form-wrap">
 <input type="text" name="" id="textField1" class="hidden" disabled>
 <input type="text" name="" id="textField2" class="hidden" disabled>

</div>
```

Comment: Hi @daredevil1234,
I just checked your code it seems working fine with "3.2.0".  i'm curious, where you have got "3.2.1". There is no such version. Please check.
http://jquery.com/download/

Comment: https://blog.jquery.com/2016/09/22/jquery-3-1-1-released/ . You can also go to the fiddle i posted and change the jquery and they have 3.2.1 available too.

Comment: please read the third edit.  I have concluded that there is something else wrong with my source code but NOT with the posted code.  will post a follow up soon if/when i identify the problem

Comment: I have a working example of the real determined issue now on the fiddle.  See fourth and hopefully final edit.

Comment: Hi @daredevil1234, I have checked your final edit and fiddle as well. Is this what exactly you want to achieve?